# Remove whitespace in url in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm passing name and id of product in my URL ,but due to space between the product name it is showing "%20"

my URL is like this:

detail/Cardon%20Black%20Rectangular%20Eyeglasses/588319df247d4b6e3397a6fa

what should i do to remove all these "%20" to make my URL clean i want it like this:

detail/CardonBlackRectangularEyeglasses/588319df247d4b6e3397a6fa

Comment: Replace your product name empty spaces with underscore _ , while you extract actual name, again replace underscore with empty.. That is the default behavior of browser to replace your empty with %20.

Comment: You can't get rid of the %20 as long as you are using the product name as identifier. Product Names are NOT Identifiers. You should use the product ID. In Angular nobody really cares about readable URLs, because Google can't load the pages anyway.

Comment: As you are passing value, obviously you want to use it in another component. So what you can do is use service to set the variable in your origin component and get the value of service on your destination component. Just a idea!!

Answer (score 2):

only way would be to replace those spaces, like Arepalli already commented.

```js
// JS function
function replaceAll(input, find, replace) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

// TypeScript function
public replaceAll(input: string, find: string, replace: string): string {
   return input.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

var productName = 'Cardon Black Rectangular Eyeglasses';
productName = replaceAll(productName, ' ', '');
console.log(productName);
```

**BUT** your server has to handle those URLs!

So maybe those spaces are required? :)